# iPadOS 14.2 - Unable to find Apple Pencil double tap settings

Tags: ipad, ipados, apple-pencil

I have an Apple Pencil 2 paired with an iPad running iPadOS 14.2. I was able to configure the double tap action in the settings somehow, but I don't know how to do it anymore.

Is this setting hidden?

It's not in the `Accessibilities -> Apple Pencil` or `Apple Pencil` in the Settings app.
Under `Apple Pencil`, I can only see `Only draw with Apple Pencil`, `Scribble`, and `Try Scribble`.

Comment: Restart your iPad then attach the Pencil to the side like you're charging it.  Open Settings and see if the double-tap option is there.  I have an iPad Pro with 14.2 and I can see the dbl-tap setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn on Bluetooth. I mean fully, not that power saving thing..
If you are in the Settings app maybe you have to restart Settings (close from the recent apps also).
This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have thesame issue: I have an iPad Pro 129 with Apple Pencil 2.
The option was there when when I setup the iPad At the beginning. Then - the day after it's gone. Identical case to teddy's one.
thanks for the help.
Mike